# Should Important Metric be tracked in separate BooleanField, or is a CharField enough?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to track stats on messages in my application. An important metric is "initial message" as this means a new conversation started. Is it better to have the initial message as a separate BooleanField, or is it enough to have "initial message" being tracked as a string in the message category CharField.

Please specify whether you recommend Model A, Model B, or another approach, and why.

I want to use this model to power charts that I show in the user dashboard of my application.

```
# Model A
class Data(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    message_channel= models.CharField(max_length=20) #Facebook, Twitter, SMS
    message_category = models.CharField(max_length=20) #initial message, reply, feedback_reply
    initial_message = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
# Model B
class Data(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    message_channel= models.CharField(max_length=20) #Facebook, Twitter, SMS
    message_category = models.CharField(max_length=20) #initial message, reply, feedback reply
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of database normalization, if you're storing information about messages in a table, the right way is that you have a foreign key between you messages table and your messages category table, then you only need to create a new row with the "Initial Message" in your category table (Model B)

Comment: Manuel, but I only plan on having one field for message category. So what is the point of creating a whole new table for message category.

Comment: It is related with the scalability of your system, today is a message, in a year could be 10 and it has not sense to create more than one field to reach the same objective

Comment: Ok, and what is danger of just using message_category = models.CharField(max_length=20) #initial message, reply, feedback_reply
And just filtering results to "initial message" string for my charts?

Comment: There is no any danger, both models could works, but B is better. One reason is that filters in database works good with numeric primary key fields (by adding the fk relationship), not with varchar fields, also you could filter with initial_message boolean = True